# Find all the combinations of a string Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I want to find all the combinations of a string in javascript. I looked up previously asked questions but there is one output missing and I don't know how to find it.

**My code is:**

```
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <label>Enter word/sentence to generate combinations:</label>
        <input type="text" name="comb"/></br>
        <input type="button" value="Get Combination" name="combbtn" onclick="substrings()"/>
        <script>
            function substrings(){
                var str=document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                var i, j, result = [];
                  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                      for (j = i + 1; j < str.length + 1; j++) {
                          result.push(str.slice(i, j));
                      }
                  }
                  alert(result);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I try "dad" as input, the expected output is:-

> d,a,da,d,dd,ad,dad

But my code somehow misses

> "dd"

How can I include it. Any help/suggestion?

Comment: dd would mean all subsequences

Comment: The question I'm facing is phrased like that. Sorry If it's misleading. All i want is to include "dd" to my output.

Comment: "dd" is *not* a substring of "dad".

Comment: But it's in the expected output. How can I include it?

Comment: @dikshamsc If that is the expected output then the question is wrong.

Comment: Well I can't really go and change the system right?

Comment: @dikshamsc Please define "substring" as used in the question - perhaps you have been given a different definition than the conventional one.

Comment: Your output has "d" twice but not "da" and "ad" and "dd" twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need to do is print all subsequences, this code would do that

```js
function printSubsequences(str){
    let len = str.length, result = [];
    for(let i=1; i<(1<<len); i++){
        let temp = "";
        for(let j=0; j<len; j++){
            if((i&(1<<j))){
                temp = temp +str.charAt(j);
            }
        }
        result.push(temp);
    }
    console.log(result);
}
printSubsequences('dad');
```

**Note** the time complexity is **exponential**

consider a n digit number, the loop

```
for(let i=1; i<(1<<len); i++)
```

covers all numbers from 1 to 2^(n-1). Since all possible combinations can be represented in this number **i**, we need to check for a given i which bits were set

```
for(let j=0; j<len; j++)
```

travels through all possible bits and checks if **(i & 2^(j-1))** is set or not, if it is set then that character is a part of the current string. here is the strings represented in 3 bits

> "d"    001 
>     "a"    010 
>     "da"   011 
>     "d"    100 
>     "dd"   101 
>     "ad"   110 
>     "dad"  111

Comment: Also could you please explain the logic on for loops and if condition. I get really confused with bitwise shift operators.

Comment: added hope it helps

Comment: 0'th bit represents "d", 1'th represents "a" and 2nd represents "d"

Answer (score 0):

#### For n characters, you want 2^n-1 possibilities

So let's use binary for it:

For n characters, let a variable run from 0 to 2^n-1.
Examine the binary digits of the variable. There will be `n` of them.

When a digit is 0, omit the character; when a digit is 1, show the corresponding character.

Obviously you don't want the empty output, and that is why you are not starting your loop variable at 0.

```js
    let str="dad";
    let n=str.length;
    for (i=1;i<2**n-1;i++) {
      let out="";
      for (c=0;c<n;c++){
        if (i & (2**c) ) {
          out += str[c];
        }
      }
    console.log(out);
    }
```

d
a
da
d
dd
ad

Comment: Well yeah.. But all i want is to include repeating subelement like dd in dad. But i don't know how to do that.